# How do I access child rows of a thead element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm new to Javascript, so I'm not sure if I'm just not getting it, or if I've found a bug in... something, though I wouldn't know what. I have a script that is loading the results of a database query, then creating a graph (with the [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) library), and then spitting out the raw data in a table. So far, this all works great.

What I would like to do next is enable the toggling of individual data lines on the graph. Rather than make an Ajax call to go back to the server and get and parse the data again, I'd like to just read the data back from the table of raw numbers, and redraw the graph -- all client side. My problem is trying to get the column names values from the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements. I can get this:

```
tbody = $("#raw_body");

console.log(tbody);
```

And see in the Firebug console:

```
[tbody#raw_body]
```

In the console, I can click through the object and see that the [0] instance has "children", etc. However, every time I try something like this:

```
console.log(tbody[0].children[0]);
```

I get:

```
undefined
```

So how do I address rows of the table for assigning to Javascript objects, like this?

```
r = tbody[0].children[0];
```

Comment: HTMLTableSectionElement (`thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`) has an HTMLCollection (array-like) called `rows` pertaining to the rows of each section. You can also use HTMLTableElement's `rows` HTMLCollection to analyze every single row in the table. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-64060425

Comment: Further to that point, you'd do yourself a great service by attaching an `id` attribute to the table, instead of the tbody. You'll have far more flexibility to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` objects have a property called `rows`. You can use that instead to loop through the rows.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/tableproperties.shtml

```
var tableObj = $("#myTable").get();
for(var i in tableObj.rows) {
    // Do something
    alert( tableObj.rows[i].innerHTML );
}
```

If you want to use jQuery:

```
var $rows = $("#raw_body tr");
$rows.each(function() {
    // Do something
    alert( $(this).html() );
});
```

Comment: Using a for...in loop is a bad idea here. That code is one prototype modification from falling apart. Use a regular for loop instead.

Comment: Why the difference in using a variable name prepended with a dollar sign ($rows) versus one with (tableObj)? (Told you I was new to Javascript!)

Comment: I still get "undefined" for `tableObj.rows`. But the "jQuery" method works. Now I know I need to study how jQuery wraps the DOM. I didn't realize that there was a difference.

Comment: This is just not working. I can `rows = $("#raw_body tr")` from the Firebug console window, but it does NOT WORK from my script. I separated some test code for hacking on this, and confirmed that it's the d3 graphing library that's somehow interfering with jQuery, even when I try to use the noConflict call.

Answer (score 3):

`$("#raw_body tbody tr")` will give you all the rows in the table with an id of raw_body.

I'm not sure what you mean by: "So how do I address rows of the table for assigning to Javascript objects, like this?"

Comment: This is definitely unnecessary. The DOM provides more than enough direct ways to grab table rows.

Comment: What is unnecessary about it? He's clearly already using jQuery so he doesn't need to add an additional library to implement my suggestion. If you think this method is unnecessary, what do you suggest?

Comment: The problem with your selector is it's going to recurse the entire DOM looking for an id, then a tbody element, then tr elements. That's far too many wasted computations. Bobince's answer basically has it down (with jQuery, anyways).

Comment: Can you post a source where you found the information that the queries work that way? I thought that it first found an element with id of `raw_body` using `getElementByID` and then looked inside that element for `tbody` and then inside that looked for `tr`. I also did some reading that jQuery does work the way I've described since version 1.3 when Sizzle was included.

Comment: That is a useful site. Thanks for taking the time to put that together. I'll be sure to bookmark it for future use.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually `.childNodes[0]`. .children() is a jquery method that scans child nodes for a specified pattern, so use

```
tbody[0].childNodes[0]
```

instead.

Comment: To clarify: `tbody` is (in OP's code) a jQuery object, while `tbody[0]` is a DOM node. That said, OP should *really* use a variable name that isn't identical to an HTML tag.

Comment: I can't get `.childNodes` to give me anything either, even if I change the name of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#raw_body")[0]
```

Returns the underlying DOM object, not the jQuery wrapper. DOM objects don't have a `children` method (*). If you want the jQuery-wrapped version, use `eq()` instead:

```
var first_row= $('#raw_body').eq(0).children().eq(0);
```

However you can omit the `.eq(0)` on the `$('#raw_body')` because there will only ever be one element that matches `#raw_body`. jQuery wrappers treat an element and a list of elements the same so you don't need to extract a single element to be able to call `children()` on it.

*: though they do have a `childNodes` property. You probably don't want to use that because then you have to worry about the Text nodes for whitespace in between the elements. However, tables in particular have `rows` and `cells` properties which are easier to use, so you could do it with:

```
var first_row= $('#raw_body')[0].rows[0];
```